# What is the syntax for kubectl can-i command?

Tags: kubernetes

How do I use the `can-i` command? It does not seem to be completely documented here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-can-i-em- (no mention of `--as`).

---

All the below results seem nonsensical:

```
kubectl auth can-i list pod --as=default3ueoaueo --as-group=system:authenticated --as-group=system:masters
yes
```

The above will return `yes` for anything after `--as=` - any user specified here.

On the other hand, the default user account (or any other I've tried) seems to have no permission at all:

```
kubectl auth can-i list pod --as=default                                                                  
no
```

and

```
kubectl auth can-i list pod --as=default:serviceaccount:default
no
```

And according to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73123 we just add `--as-group=system:authenticated` but that doesn't work either:

```
kubectl auth can-i list pod --as=serviceaccount:default  --as-group=system:authenticated 
no
```

Answer (score 11):

The usage of `'--as'` argument with `kubectl` command is known as "User impersonation", and it's documented in official documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#user-impersonation).

If you are trying to impersonate user as an API resource like 'serviceaccounts', 
the proper syntax is: `'--as=system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default`'

Comment: exanple '--as=system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default'